# How to fix data deletes only first row but it does not delete second and any rows? Ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to delete data using Ajax with no refresh, the deletion of data works but with one problem, the delete only works with the 1st row, if I try to delete second and onwards rows, the delete does not work as expected. Is there a way to do this?

Script:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
      event.preventDefault();
      var subject = $(this).attr("id");
      var section = $("#section").val();
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")){
        $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>loadings/remove_subject",
          method:"POST",
          cache:false,
          data:{subject:subject,section:section},
          success:function(data){
            // alert(section);
            toastr.warning('Submission has beeen removed');
            load_data();
            return true;
          }
        });
      }else{
        return false;
      }
      // alert('Data Deleted Successfully');
  });
```

Input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="section" value="'.$row->section.'" />
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" name="delete" id="'.$row->subject.'"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> </button>
```

Model:

```
function remove_subject($subject,$section){
    $this->db->where('section',$section);
    $this->db->where('subject',$subject);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_college_grades');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass event in function of document as a parameter.
2. You only have a problem with your hidden item value.
   When you press button first time, return a response from the function using 'yes' or 'not'
   If ajax return 'yes':

   $("#section").val('');
3. When a button press just put $(this).val() in value of hidden field.

Comment: if it is possible sir, can you provide a more detailed code, please?